# Powershell | Combining multiple Arrays and compare them to a table

Tags: arrays, excel, powershell, dns

I have encountered a new problem and I don't even know where exactly to start explaining. I will try my best, if something is unclear just ask me please.

I have an Excel workbook with informations (multiple rows) about DNS records - pretty similar to the powershell DNS syntax. e.g:

```
HostName    RecordType    TimeStamp    TimeToLive    RecordData
@           A             0            00:05:00      127.0.0.1
```

I read them as arrays with the following little code - not very fast, but it works!:

```
#Read Excel
        $row = [int]2
        do {
            if ($Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,1).Text) {$ZoneName      += $Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,1).Text}
                                                  $HostName      += $Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,2).Text
                                                  $RecordType    += $Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,3).Text
                                                  $TimeStamp     += $Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,4).Text
                                                  $TimeToLive    += $Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,5).Text
                                                  $RecordData    += $Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,6).Text
            $row = $row + [int] 1
           } until (!$Sheet4.Cless.Item($row,2))
```

Now I have 6 arrays all stuck with information in different arrays, but all with the same amount of lines.

And now the tricky (atleast for me!) part:

I would like to stuff those 6 arrays into some special array I do not know, or in some sort of table I do not know how to create.
Why?
Because I want to compare those lines to this code ($Records to be specific):

```
        $ZoneNames = (Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName $DnsServer).zonename
        $ZoneNames | foreach {$Records = (Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DnsServer -ZoneName $_)}
```

$Records[0] would show me this (e.g.):

```
HostName                  RecordType Timestamp            TimeToLive      RecordData                                        
--------                  ---------- ---------            ----------      ----------                                        
@                         A          0                    00:05:00        127.0.0.1
```

BUT: If I go deeper: $Records[0].RecordData:

```
IPv4Address                                                        PSComputerName                                                    
-----------                                                        --------------                                                    
127.0.0.1
```

So I would need to recreate this (above) sort of hierarchy to compare them (If I am right?).

I have tried it with a table like this (didn't work):

```
#Create Table object
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable “$ExcelRecords”
#Define Columns
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn HostName,([string])
$col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn RecordType,([string])
$col4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn TimeStamp,([string])
$col5 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn TimeToLive,([string])
$col6 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn RecordData,([string])
#Add the Columns
$table.columns.add($col2)
$table.columns.add($col3)
$table.columns.add($col4)
$table.columns.add($col5)
$table.columns.add($col6)
#Create a row
$r = $table.NewRow()
#Enter data in the row
$r.HostName = $HostName[$counter]
$r.RecordType = $RecordType[$counter]
$r.TimeStamp = $TimeStamp[$counter]
$r.TimeToLive = $TimeToLive[$counter]
$r.RecordData = $RecordData[$counter]
$RecordData
#Add the row to the table
$table.Rows.Add($r)
```

Tried comparing like this (didn't work):

```
if ($records[0] -like $table[0]) {write-host "works"}
```

This did work:

```
if ($records[0].hostname -like $table[0].hostname) {write-host "works"}
works
```

This did not (I guess this is the root of my problems):

```
if ($Records[0].RecordData -like $table[0].RecordData) {write-host "works"}
```

My main objective:
Check if there are Records on the DNS-Server, which aren't stated in the Excel sheet and delete them from the DNS-Server!

If you read through all the text, thanks for doing that! Appreciate every help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by creating an array of PS objects from your spreadsheet data.

```
#Read Excel
        $row = [int]2
        $DNS_Records = 
        do {
            if ($Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,1).Text) {
              New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                ZoneName      = $Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,1).Text
                HostName      = $Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,2).Text
                RecordType    = $Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,3).Text
                TimeStamp     = $Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,4).Text
                TimeToLive    = $Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,5).Text
                RecordData    = $Sheet4.Cells.Item($Row,6).Text
               }
             }
           } until (!$Sheet4.Cless.Item($row,2))
```

Comment: That was something I have been looking for. Thx for that. But do you know if it is possible to split the Recorddata into 2 subobjects with this cmdlet?

Comment: I don't understand that question.  If you're wanting to compare what you're getting back from the Get-DnsServerZone objects to that spreadsheet data, I'd convert both to csv and then use compare-object on the csv strings.

Comment: Can I divide the Property RecordData into 2 more properties one level lower? Some sort of sublevel. e.g. $DNS_records[0].RecordData.IPv4Address

Comment: Sorry I have invested several hours into this idea of yours. Couldn't get anywhere. Sorry, but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: IMHO, you're going about this the wrong way. You need to simplify what you're getting back from Get-DnsServerResourceRecord to match the objects created from you spreadsheed data, not complicate the spreadsheet data objects to match what your getting back from Get-DnsServerResourceRecord .

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted, because your idea of simplifying worked. Even though I didn't use your PS-object, I used my table, because it was more comfortable for me to iterate trough it row by row. Thank you very much! Sorry that I needed so much time, but this was a tough one for me